# How to run a PHP script after a few seconds

Tags: php, ajax

I need to run a php script after a user has been on a page after 15seconds. Im pretty sure it will require ajax but I have no clue how it would be coded.

Comment: So what are you asking for?  Nobody here is going to write the script for you.

Comment: Type your "question"-title in google and i am pretty sure u will find ur answer.

Comment: It *might* require AJAX.  Of course, if you trigger the script from the client-side with AJAX then you accept the risk that it might not get triggered.  The user could have JavaScript disabled, or could navigate away within the 15-second window.  If you need it to be more reliable, you'd need to do it entirely server-side.

Comment: how about a CRON job?

Comment: @Gary I was not expecting that.. I was expecting maybe a nudge in the right direction..

Comment: Note that David's solution requires you to run a script in the background of your server. A regular webspace server won't do. You'll need one with CLI support for PHP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to set a jQuery/JavaScript setTimeout() function which after 15 seconds triggers an AJAX call. But doing it this way isn't reliable at all.

Here you go:
http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/settimeout-example/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Or use PHPs sleep function
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: I believe `sleep` is a blocking function. The user would have to wait for 15 seconds before he/she finally receives anything...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method setTimeout() (see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)). The method takes at least 2 parameters. The first is a function and the second a delay in milliseconds. What setTimeout() does is calling the method after the delay passed away.

So, in the method you could do an AJAX request.

Comment: Which is effectively the same as my answer haha

Comment: Also, w3schools [is not a reliable resource](http://www.w3fools.com/), so please do not link to it if there are better resources out there, such as the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout).

Comment: Good point! MDN is indeed a better resource.